# How can I produce columnar output from 2-level grouping in XML?

Tags: xslt, grouping

I have the following xml:

#### input

```
<page>
 <group category="cat1">
  <item fileunder="#">.45 colt</item>
  <item fileunder="#">8 queens</item>
  <item fileunder="#">9 lives</item>
  <item fileunder="#">99 bottles of beer</item>
  <item fileunder="A">An innocent man</item>
  <item fileunder="A">Academy awards</item>
  <item fileunder="B">Before the dawn</item>
 </group>
 <group category="cat2">
  <item fileunder="R">Rows of houses</item>
 </group>
</page>
```

The input items are already sorted.

#### desired output

I want to produce a 3-column HTML table for every `group`, with a subheading (a 3-column spanning cell) for each distinct `fileunder`, optimally presented in a top-down, then-next-column (the items are already sorted):

```
<table>
 <tr><td colspan="3">#</td></tr>
 <tr><td>.45 colt</td><td>9 lives</td><td>99 bottles of beer</td></tr>
 <tr><td>8 queens</td></tr>
 <tr><td colspan="3">A</td></tr>
 <tr><td>An innocent man</td><td>Academy awards</td></tr>
 <tr><td colspan="3">B</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Before the dawn</td></tr>
</table>
<table>
 <tr><td colspan="3">R</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Rows of houses</td></tr>
</table>
```

I can live if the items are presented as left-to-right, then-next-row.

What I have so far is:

#### current xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="itm_grp" match="/page/group/item" use="concat(../@category,':',@fileunder)"/>
<xsl:template match="page/group">
  <table>
  <xsl:for-each select="item[.=key('itm_grp',concat(../@category,':',@fileunder))[1]]">
    <tr><td colspan="3"><xsl:value-of select="@fileunder"/></td></tr>
    <xsl:variable name="nodeset" select="key('itm_grp',concat(../@category,':',@fileunder))"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$nodeset[position() mod 3=1]">
      <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::item[1]"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::item[2]"/></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which produces a left-to-right, then-next-row output (non-optimal); however, the `following-sibling` selects produce a “bleed-through” effect:

```
#
.45 colt            8 queens         9 lives
99 bottles of beer  An innocent man  Academy awards
A
An innocent man     Academy awards   Before the dawn
B
Before the dawn     
R
Rows of houses
```

As you can see, `fileunder` `#` has two A items, and `fileunder` `A` has one B item.

So, my question is:

How can I produce the desired output (column-wise)?
If I can't do that, how can I have the row-wise output avoiding the “bleeding”?

Please note that I have very little experience with XSLT, so if my code is blatantly inefficient/idiotic/whatever, please feel free to educate me by replacing all of it!

NB: XSLT version 1, so apparently no `index-of` function is available.

Comment: Could you, please, explain why "8 queens" is only in the second row of the desired output? It comes *second* in document order -- then why shouldn't it be second in the first row? It would be good if you could also update the question with this explanation.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev 8 queens is in the second row because the OP wants 'optimally presented in a top-down, then-next-column' order. In other words the spatial order of cells should be top-to-bottom, and **then** left-to-right. His current solution is the transposition of this.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin, Sorry, but this isn't what the provided desired output looks like -- then "99 bottles of beer" should also be in the second row -- following "8 queens"

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Yes. Absolutely correct. There is a small contradiction between the OP's narrative and the listing, and you have discovered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight contradiction between your narrative and your listed expected output. You have asked for top-down, then left-right column fill order, which you have so in the listing for the non-empty values, but not for the empties. This spatial order implies that a whole column must be filled out before the next column can begin. I have assumed that your listing was a mistake and what your really want in output is ...

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">#</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>.45 colt</td>
    <td>9 lives</td>
    <td>&npsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8 queens</td>
    <td>99 bottles of beer</td>
    <td>&npsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>An innocent man</td>
    <td>Academy awards</td>
    <td>&npsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Before the dawn</td>
    <td>&npsp;</td>
    <td>&npsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">R</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rows of houses</td>
    <td>&npsp;</td>
    <td>&npsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

... which is consistent top-down, then left-right column fill order.

**This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet...**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:key name="kItemByFile" match="item" use="concat(../@category,':',@fileunder)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <html lang="en">
   <head><title>Songs</title></head>
   <body>  
     <xsl:apply-templates select="*/group" />
   </body>  
 </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="group">
  <xsl:variable name="cat" select="concat(@category,':')" />
  <table> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[
      generate-id() = generate-id(key('kItemByFile',concat($cat,@fileunder))[1])]" 
      mode="group-head" />
  </table> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item" mode="group-head">
  <xsl:variable name="items"
     select="key('kItemByFile',concat(../@category,':',@fileunder))" />
  <xsl:variable name="row-count" select="ceiling( count($items) div 3)" />
  <tr><td colspan="3"><xsl:value-of select="@fileunder" /></td></tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="$items[position() &lt;= $row-count]">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="row">  
      <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$items" />
      <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$pos" />
      <xsl:with-param name="row-count" select="$row-count" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>  
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item" mode="row">
  <xsl:param name="items" select="/.." />
  <xsl:param name="row" select="1" />
  <xsl:param name="row-count" select="1" />
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="
       $items[(position() mod $row-count) = ($row mod $row-count)]" mode="td" />
    <xsl:variable name="full-cols" select="floor((count($items) div $row-count))" />
    <xsl:variable name="part-col" select="number($row &lt;
                 ((count($items) mod $row-count) + 1))" />
    <xsl:variable name="empties" select="3 - ($full-cols + $part-col)" />
    <xsl:for-each select="(document('')/*/*)[position() &lt;= $empties]">
      <xsl:call-template name="empty-cell" />
    </xsl:for-each> 
  </tr>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item" mode="td">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="empty-cell">
  <td>&#160;</td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...when applied to this input...**

```
<page>
 <group category="cat1">
  <item fileunder="#">.45 colt</item>
  <item fileunder="#">8 queens</item>
  <item fileunder="#">9 lives</item>
  <item fileunder="#">99 bottles of beer</item>
  <item fileunder="A">An innocent man</item>
  <item fileunder="A">Academy awards</item>
  <item fileunder="B">Before the dawn</item>
 </group>
 <group category="cat2">
  <item fileunder="R">Rows of houses</item>
 </group>
</page>
```

**...yields...**

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Songs</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">#</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>.45 colt</td>
        <td>9 lives</td>
        <td> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8 queens</td>
        <td>99 bottles of beer</td>
        <td> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>An innocent man</td>
        <td>Academy awards</td>
        <td> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Before the dawn</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">R</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rows of houses</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note**
For the empty cells in the output, when viewing the lexical HTML, you will get either `&nbsp;` or the literal white space equivalent. It is XSLT processor implementation dependant, but should not cause you any concern because it is model-equivalent.

Comment: It seems that the “empties” handling is not required for all browsers that I could verify on; also, in some cases, the code produced a fourth column (although containing only NBSP).

Comment: Yes, the rendering behaviour if there are missing cells is browser dependant. I remember the old Netscape browser would behave very badly if there were missing `td` cells.

Comment: About the case that produces the fourth column - Could you post it please? So I can verify and correct any errors.

Comment: when a `fileunder` has a multiple-of-3 count of items.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to fix that:

```
<xsl:variable name="header" select="@fileunder"/>
...
<xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::item[@fileunder=$header][1]"/>
<xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::item[@fileunder=$header][2]"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I picked Sean's answer because it covered the desired output.